# Unable to implement has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-one

I am trying to create an account management system that allows an account to have one billing address.  I want the account and address to have their own controller and model. An admin user would create a new account then be redirected to create a new billing address for this account.  The first part works, I am able to create the account, but the second only saves the account_id attribute to the addresses table.  Below is my code:

accounts_controller

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
 def new
   @account = Account.new
 end  
 def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
    @account.build_address
   if @account.save
     flash[:success] = "Customer Account has been successfully created!"
     redirect_to '/newaddress'
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end
end
```

addresses_controller

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController  
  def new
    @address = Address.new
  end
  def create
    @account = Account.find(params[:account])
    @address = @account.create_address(params[:address])
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

account_model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  attr_accessible :contactFirstName, :contactLastName, :contactEmail, :contactPhone, :business_name
end
```

address_model

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :state, :street, :zipCode   
  belongs_to :account
end
```

I also added the following to my routes.rb file

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :addresses
end
```

Last, below is the schema for the relavant tables

```
create_table "accounts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "contactEmail"
  t.string   "contactFirstName"
  t.string   "contactLastName"
  t.string   "contactPhone"
  t.datetime "joinDate"
  t.string   "business_name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
create_table "addresses", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "city"
  t.string   "state"
  t.string   "street"
  t.string   "zipCode"
  t.integer  "account_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

(I am still new to programming and rails so I posted as much as I thought would be relevant.)

Added Log from when I open the new account page and then proceed to the new address page.

```
Started GET "/newaccount" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Sep 20 17:21:56 -0500 2011
  Processing by AccountsController#new as HTML
Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered accounts/_account_fields.html.erb (13.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (1.2ms)
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (19.4ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered accounts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (50.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 168ms (Views: 64.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)

Started POST "/accounts" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Sep 20 17:22:11 -0500 2011
  Processing by AccountsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Next", "account"=>{"business_name"=>"FooBar", "contactLastName"=>"Bar", "contactPhone"=>"1231231234", "contactEmail"=>"foo@bar.com", "contactFirstName"=>"Foo"}, "authenticity_token"=>"lJG89TIjcJighmFUWLg1uR9sJq0CHLvceeLH9QNocGY=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `accounts` WHERE (LOWER(`accounts`.`contactEmail`) = LOWER('foo@bar.com')) LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.2ms)  describe `accounts`
  AREL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `accounts` (`created_at`, `contactFirstName`, `business_name`, `contactPhone`, `updated_at`, `contactEmail`, `contactLastName`, `joinDate`) VALUES ('2011-09-20 22:22:11', 'Foo', 'FooBar', '1231231234', '2011-09-20 22:22:11', 'foo@bar.com', 'Bar', NULL)
  SQL (1.5ms)  describe `addresses`
  AREL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `addresses` (`zipCode`, `state`, `city`, `updated_at`, `account_id`, `street`, `created_at`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-09-20 22:22:11', 31, NULL, '2011-09-20 22:22:11')
  SQL (26.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3500/newaddress
Completed 302 Found in 85ms

Started GET "/newaddress" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Sep 20 17:22:11 -0500 2011
  Processing by AddressesController#new as HTML
Rendered addresses/_address_fields.html.erb (83.4ms)
Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (1.4ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (17.1ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.9ms)
Rendered addresses/new.html.erb within layouts/application (113.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 126ms (Views: 119.6ms | ActiveRecord: 30.3ms)

Started POST "/newaddress" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Sep 20 17:22:29 -0500 2011
  Processing by AddressesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"address"=>{"city"=>"Boston", "street"=>"123 Main St", "zipCode"=>"02222", "state"=>"MA"}, "commit"=>"Create", "authenticity_token"=>"lJG89TIjcJighmFUWLg1uR9sJq0CHLvceeLH9QNocGY=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
Rendered addresses/_address_fields.html.erb (10.3ms)
Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (1.2ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (17.2ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.9ms)
Rendered addresses/new.html.erb within layouts/application (40.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 47.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: I can get it to work if the forms are on the same page by using fields_for :address. This makes me think that when I have each form on its own page I am not passing it the correct account_id so that it knows where to write to in the addresses table.

Comment: I would use fields_for then and separate them visually with Ajax if needed (e.g. If you need it to look like Step 1, Step 2, etc...

Answer (score 0):

As quick look, you are passing only params[:account], tail log and see what you need

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController  
 def new
   @address = Address.new
  end
 def create
    @account = Account.find(params[:account])
   @address = @account.create_address(params[:address])
   redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

Ass you added log, you can see now that when you post newaddress

```
 Parameters: {"address"=>{"city"=>"Boston", "street"=>"123 Main St", "zipCode"=>"02222", "state"=>"MA"}, "commit"=>"Create", "authenticity_token"=>"lJG89TIjcJighmFUWLg1uR9sJq0CHLvceeLH9QNocGY=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
```

and your controller have

```
   def create
@account = Account.find(params[:account])
@address = @account.create_address(params[:address])
redirect_to root_path
```

end

As you can see there are no **@account = Account.find(params[:account])**

So you account is null, you may add hidden field with account_id to form or catch other way depends of of your app.

Comment: I took a look at the log but I still don't see what I'm doing wrong. I can see that the POST '/accounts' is creating the account_id for the addresses field but POST '/newaddress' is not creating anything.  I'm not sure what else I need to pass it.

Comment: paste the log when you tried to created to create an address.

Comment: I added the log. Thanks for your help.  Also, the users table is the table for the admin user who is creating accounts and associated billing addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The line in in the Address class looks wrong to me (take out the _attributes):

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :city, :state, :street,  :zipCode   
    belongs_to :account
 end
```

Comment: I did notice that.  I had tried adding "_attributes" based on someones suggestion but have now removed it. Even w/o it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please comment out the attr_accessible in Account.rb and let me know what you get

Comment: I commented it out but it is still not working. The post method for /newaddress just doesnt seem to be doing anything.